# uint8_t different decimal values for same binary

Tags: c++

I have the following issue using an ARM® Cortex™-M4F CPU running mbedOS 5.9.

Say I have the binary value `10101000` and that I also have the following union/struct:

```
union InputWord_u
    {
        uint8_t all;

        struct BitField_s
        {
            uint8_t start   : 1; // D7
            uint8_t select  : 3; // D6, D5, D4
            uint8_t payload : 4; // D3, D2, D1, D0
        } bits;
    };
```

I have a simple program where I access my word and assign the values as such:

```
InputWord_u word;
word.bits.start = 0b1;
word.bits.select = 0b010;
word.bits.payload = 0b1000;
```

Therefore, `word.all == 10101000` and is a `uint8_t`.

If I print this as such `printf("%u", word.all);` then I receive the value of `133`.

If I then define the following `uint8_t`:

```
uint8_t value = 0b10101000;
```

And print this using `printf("%u", value);` then I receive the value `168`.

I expect both values to equal 168.

I appreciate that this is likely me grossly misunderstanding how a Struct is represented in memory. Nevertheless, could someone please explain what is exactly going on?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the endianness on your system? I recommend examining the actual bit values of both variables and comparing/analysing them.

Comment: I believe it's little-endian. It's an ARM® Cortex™-M4F CPU running mbedOS.

Comment: Actually I just realised endianness probably doesn't come into it, sorry. Still, bit compare...

Comment: Have you read back each bitfield as well, and printed them? Have you printed the intermediate values of `all` as you assign the bitfields? Have you assigned your expected value to `all` and then read out the value of each bitfield for comparison?

Comment: @Useless That's a useful suggestion, I'll do that and see what we get. Cheers.

Comment: If there is any padding in there, you should be able to tell by checking whether `sizeof(InputWord_u) > sizeof(uint8_t)`

Comment: They're both 1 byte in size and, if I assign `word.all = 0b10101000` then it prints 168. Time to read back the bitfields and see what's going on...

Comment: Note that this way of working with unions has undefined behavior in C++ (but not in C): see [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/673852).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard guarantees hardly anything about the representation of bit-fields.

> Therefore, `word.all == 10101000`

What you've tripped over here is that you've assumed that the bit-fields are packed starting from most significant bit to least significant.

However, it appears that your bit fields were stored in the reverse order, and in fact `word.all == 1000'010'1`. To get the result you expect, you could reorder the bit-fields:

```
struct BitField_s
{
    uint8_t payload : 4; // D3, D2, D1, D0
    uint8_t select  : 3; // D6, D5, D4
    uint8_t start   : 1; // D7
} bits;
```

But be aware that bit-fieds are not portable: Other systems might not have the same order.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you calculated value in reversed way, like

`(start << 7) | (select << 4) | payload`

And actual value is calculated like

`(payload << 4) | (select << 1) | start`

So your bitfield starts with less-significant parts of `uint8`. It has nothing to do with little-endianness of system, because little-endianness defines orders of bytes in `uint16`, `uint32` e.t.c.

Order of bits of bitfield inside byte is defined by compiler. For example, [MSVC uses low-to-high order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx), as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Binary value of 133 and 168

```
133 = 10000101
168 = 10101000
```

sums it that actual alignment is different from your assumed alignment.

It seems that it as arranging in the following manner:

```
----     ---     -
         all
payload  select  start
```

And you are assuming the following order

```
-     ---  ----
start all  payload
```

I also think different compiler has different alignment.